# Swift wrong syntax?

Tags: ios, swift

Im following the swift tutorials at https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099

ive created some buttons which i want to handle in a method.

To handle the buttons I have:

```
@IBAction func appendDigit(sender:UIButtion {
    let digit  = sender.currentTitle
    println("digit" = \(digit)")
}
```

This gives me an error on the prinln that states

```
   Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ";"
```

So I tried adding ; after the println and after the declartion of digit but the error remains.

This question might be very easy to fix but im pretty much stuck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question was just a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the right parenthesis after `UIButton`.

You also have a hanging quote mark in the `println` statement; that line should be

```
println("digit = \(digit)")
```

Comment: @SvenB: It's fine to leave the question open.

Comment: I don't think you can remove a question if an answer has upvotes. Not positive though.